BFS-trees and distances
I am reading "Graph Theory" by Bondy and Murty and I am confused by the following problem in the book (it is exercise 6.1.7a in the book):
For some connected graph $G$, define $\sigma(G) = \Sigma \{d(u, v)\}$ for all $u, v \in V(G)$, where $d(u,v)$ is the distance between the vertices.
Suppose now we have a connected graph $G$. Let $T_v$ be a breadth-first search tree of $G$ rooted at $v$. Show that $\sum_{v \in V} \sigma (T_v) = 2(n-1) \sigma(G)$.
Here's what if have so far: 
Since the distance between two vertices in $T_v$ is the same as their distance in $G$, $\sigma(T_v)$ is just the sum of distances $d(u, v)$ for every other $u$ in the graph $G$. The sum of $\sigma(T_v)$ is then $2\sigma(G)$, because the distance between each pair $(u, v)$ is counted twice in $\sum_{v \in V} \sigma(T_v)$. Why is it $2(n-1) \sigma(G)$?

What do you mean by "for every other u
in the graph"?

Also is there any other constraint on $G$, like how its fully connected or something? Because as it stands, you can take $G$ itself to be a tree where $\sum_{v \in V} \sigma (T_v) = n \sigma(G) \not= 2(n-1)\sigma(G)$

By "for every other $u$ in the graph", I mean "for all $u$ in $G$, where $u \neq v$.
There are no other constraints.

Does $\sigma(T_\upsilon)$ mean $\sum (d(x, y)) \quad \forall x,y \in V$, or $\sum (d(x, \upsilon)) \quad \forall x \in V$

The part b of this exercise is

b) Deduce that every connected graph $G$ has a spanning tree $T$ such that $\sigma(T) \le 2(1 - 1/n)\sigma(G)$.

That's why I guess that it's just a typo in part a, and the task is to prove that
$$\sum_{v \in V} \sigma(T_v) \le 2(n - 1)\sigma(G).$$
To prove this statement we should note that $d_{T_v}(u, w) \le d(u, v) + d(w, v)$. It gives us $\sigma(T_v) \le (n - 1)\sum_{u \in V}d(v, u)$. Summing up for all $v$ we prove the desired inequality.
The equality holds for complete graphs $G$ only, because existence of pair of non-adjacent vertices gives a tree of height at least $2$ and strict inequality since our upper bound for any two vertices from the same subtree is bigger than the actual distance by at least $2$.
